# PHP: Array ordering

Tags: php

I have about 50 items in a list. I calculate their value using an algorythm and I add their value in an array.

Suppose I get this when the loop is over:

```
$vals = (51, 23, 77, 3, 8, 31, 17, 102, 87, (...));
```

**Now, how can I get they keys of the 3 highest values in the array?**

In the above example, I would like to get:

- 8 (key of 102)
- 9 (key of 87)
- 3 (key of 77)

PS: I don't want to insert those datas in a DB and then select them with Order clause, I'm sure there is an easier way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$vals = array(51, 23, 77, 3, 8, 31, 17, 102, 87);
arsort($vals);    
$keys = array_slice(array_keys($vals), 0, 3);

var_dump($keys); // array(3) { [0]=> int(7) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(2) }
```

The result is not the same you'd like to get, because arrays in php are 0-indexed

Comment: How can I get the key instead of the value?

Answer (score 2):

sort them descending, extract 3. first values, done!

```
arsort($vals);
echo  "$vals[0], $vals[1], $vals[2]";
```